# Как использовать ymaps.geocode на react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yandex-maps-api, geocode

Для достижения цели:

- получил ключ для "JavaScript API и HTTP Геокодер" и подключил API в файл index.html со своим ключом
- добавил в конструктор Map: modules={['geocode']}
- и в конструкторе Map написал: onLoad={(ymaps) => (ymaps.geocode('Москва').then(result => console.log('какой-то текст')))}

Все это запускаю на localhost.

В итоге в консоль выводится ошибка: GET https://api-maps.yandex.ru/services/se... net::ERR_ABORTED 429 (Too ... Many Requests)

Может кто-нибудь сможет что-то подсказать. Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Ключ необходимо вписывать в параметр query у YMaps Provider:

```
<YMaps
  query={{
    ns: "use-load-option",
    apikey: "ваш ключ api",
    load: "загружаемые модули"
  }}
>
```